# VBA IF NOT [function] then [code] runs code regardless of function output

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I wrote the following code:

```
Sub iojh()

If Not foo() Then MsgBox ("hi")

End Sub

Function foo() As Integer
foo = 0
End Function
```

It shows the msgbox when foo = 0 and when foo = 1. Why is this? I found a workaround using an If Else statement, but I'd like to know what's going on and if there's a better solution. This is my workaround:

```
Sub iojh()

If foo() Then
    '
Else
    MsgBox ("hi")
End If

End Sub

Function foo() As Integer
foo = 1
End Function
```

Comment: In vba, `True = -1` and `False = 0`

Comment: foo returns an integer. Not,  applied to an integer, is the binary not operator. Integer 0 when binary Not is apply becomes -1. Integer 1 when binary Not is applied become -2. Both -1 and -2 when converted to Boolean tests as True.

Comment: Install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and then take a look at the code inpsections.

Comment: If, for some reason, `foo` _needs_ to return an integer, you can use `If Not CBool(foo()) Then ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Boolean values are either True or False.**

At a bit level, computers store that information as either a `1`, or a `0`, respectively.

**In vba, True = -1 and False = 0 - but.. why?**

However, almost all computer systems hold their bits in patterns of 8 bits and multiples thereof. *For the ease of display*, let's consider an 8 bit system - where the data is stored in a byte:

`0` = `False` as a bit, becomes `00000000` as a byte - all off.

`1` = `True`  as a bit, becomes `11111111` as a byte - all on.

As you can see, ***all*** the bits in the `True` byte are flipped.

The other thing to remember is that in this case these bytes use 'sign-magnitude' representation and the left most bit is used as the sign (+ve or -ve). So where the byte contains `11111111`, when converted back to a decimal comes out as `-1`.

Another way to think of it: adding 1 to `11111111` would result in `00000000` as the extra bit is lost, so subtracting 1 from `00000000` results in `11111111`.

**Writing** *Decimal* **1 to boolean**

When you write `1` to a boolean data type in vba, it must be represented as either all zeros: `00000000`, or all ones: `11111111`. The conversion is set up such that it becomes `11111111`. Seemingly, writing ***any bit*** to the value causes all bits to become '1' - resulting in an output of `True`.

**Writing Not (** *Decimal* **1) to boolean**

When you write (or test) `Not (1)` to a boolean though, the `Not` operand is performed *first*. But, thinking of those numbers as bits, `1` = `00000001`, so `Not (1)` = `11111110`. Again, as per the rule above, as at least 1 (in this case, 7) bits are on, **all switch on**. This results is an output of `True`.

So as you can see, both `1` and `Not(1)` when converted to boolean become True, causing your issue.

I would recommend considering changing your system to use 0 and -1, or code a small converter function to keep things aligned.

Note: I have had stretch my memory further back than I'd like to admit in answering the above, so forgive me if some of the language or understanding has shifted since I left school (when 8-bit was the norm)- but I think it all still holds true. I note that SQL bit columns do not work the same way for instance due to the way they're stored, but that is not the question here.

Comment: Wow! That was awesome! Thank you! Per your advise, I changed "foo = 0" to "foo = -1" and I'm seeing the results that I expected. Unfortunately, I studied computational mathematics in school. I wouldn't be familiar with appropriate language. Yours is good though! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Delcare `foo()` function as `Boolean type. Try-

```
Sub iojh()
    If Not foo() Then MsgBox ("hi")
End Sub

Function foo() As Boolean
    foo = 0
End Function
```

Comment: If you declare `foo` as Boolean, you should only assign a Boolean to it, not a number

Comment: @FunThomas When you will declare a variable or function as `Boolean` and assign value `o` or `1` then system will automatically treat it as `Boolean` logic `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: That worked! I also noticed that --- If Not 1 Then MsgBox ("hi")  --- runs the msgbox

Comment: @user348731 Because `0` zero is treated as `FALSE` others integer treated as `TRUE`.

Comment: Of course it does. In VBA. It's simply wrong to rely on implicit conversions. There is **absolute no reason** to assign a 1 or a 3 or a -9000 or a 0 to a boolean. A boolean can only hold True and False and you should assign only True an False to it. If you want to check if a value is not equal 0, check for not equal and assign the result to the boolean. As a programmer, you don't care how a boolean is represented or you are doing something wrong

Comment: @FunThomas Agreed. Boolean values do not need to assign integer. But in some cases Microsoft also uses integer in place of boolean variable. Very funny.

Comment: @Harun24hr probably because Boolean was not a type in C before C99, and most of APIs in Microsoft libraries date from that time.